# naming rows in time series

Tags: r, time-series

my question is simple. I would like to name the rows of a time series (two time series) data so that each rowname is repeated twice but with a "-1" and "-2" separating them so that it looks like this:

```
1-1  7.116864
1-2  6.898450
2-1  7.224002
2-2  6.993221
3-1  7.266787
3-2  7.483816
4-1  8.055825
4-2  7.993788
5-1 8.895424
5-2 9.097769
7-1  7.116864
7-2  6.898450
10-1  7.224002
10-2  6.993221
```

I know I can easily name rows with using do.NULL like this `dimnames(matrixm) <- list(rownames(matrixm, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "row"))` for a matrix matrixm but 
here my first question is

How do I name is sequentially as show above for the two-time series from t 1-1, 1-2 to t 5-1 and 5-2?

Secondly, can I also select other arbitrary rows and name them same way e.g the 7th and 10th time series?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to do since you don't give a reproducible example. I think you can use `paste` to create your rownames and then merge them using `rbind` and `order`. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
t1 <- as.matrix(rnorm(5))
t2 <- as.matrix(rnorm(5))
rownames(t1) <- paste(1:5,1,sep='-')
rownames(t2) <- paste(1:5,2,sep='-')
```

Then you merge the matrix using `rbind` and order them :

```
tt <- rbind(t1,t2)
tt[order(rownames(tt)),,drop=FALSE]

          [,1]
1-1 -0.6264538
1-2 -0.8204684
2-1  0.1836433
2-2  0.4874291
3-1 -0.8356286
3-2  0.7383247
4-1  1.5952808
4-2  0.5757814
5-1  0.3295078
5-2 -0.3053884
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation:

```
# length of your time series vector
n <- 20
# simulate the values of the series vector
x <- matrix(rnorm(n,5,0.5),nr=n,nc=1)
# assign the rownames to the matrix
rownames(x) <- c(t(cbind(paste(1:(n/2),"1",sep="-"),
                         paste(1:(n/2),"2",sep="-"))))

# > x
#          [,1]
# 1-1  5.582177
# 1-2  5.320359
# 2-1  4.958729
# 2-2  4.630183
# 3-1  5.357314
# 3-2  4.287579
# 4-1  4.664101
# 4-2  5.299628
# 5-1  5.480967
# 5-2  5.368158
# 6-1  4.697664
# 6-2  5.191149
# 7-1  4.418201
# 7-2  4.399364
# 8-1  4.845039
# 8-2  4.785453
# 9-1  5.933396
# 9-2  4.035960
# 10-1 4.539947
# 10-2 4.162826
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a combination of the rep and paste commands like so:

```
# simulate your data
m <- matrix(runif(20,6,10))
# give names to rows
rownames(m) <- paste(rep(1:(nrow(m)/2), each=2), rep(1:2, nrow(m)/2), sep="-")
```